# Por que o Kotlin usa uma forma de declarar funções e variáveis diferente da "tradicional"?

Tags: funções, característica-linguagem, kotlin, declaração-de-variável

Tradicionalmente o tipo de retorno e o tipo da variável são indicados no inicio, antes do nome:

```
public int soma(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
```

No Kotlin ele é indicado depois:

```
fun sum(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
    return a + b
}
```

Quais os fundamentos por detrás dessa opção?

Comment: Não acredito que seja um motivo revelador ou algo do tipo. acredito que seja um diferencial apenas semântico. Como no php por exemplo que declaramos variáveis com o $ na frente e não muda absolutamente nada. Apenas semântica rs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exatamente, esse "tradicional" bem entre aspas. A forma que chama de tradicional vem do estilo C, que é considerado ruim por muitos.

Complica o compilador porque gera contexto para o *parser*, dificulta a inferência de tipos, exige uma palavra chave antes da declaração quando não quer dizer o tipo (embora Kotlin errou nesta, na minha opinião<sup>*</sup>).

Muitas pessoas também consideram mais legível assim, fica mais fluido. O nome da variável é mais importante que seu tipo. De fato em tipos como nomes grandes até você achar o nome da variável é uma tristeza:

```
val shapeInfo: HashMap[Shape, (String, String)] = makeInfo()
val HashMap[Shape, (String, String)] shapeInfo := makeInfo()
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/DeclarationSyntax.kt).

Qual você acha o nome da variável mais facilmente?

---

<sup>*</sup>Eu preferia algo assim:

```
variavel := 1
constante ::= 1
variavel : Int
```

Mais fácil ainda de achar o nome, não? Sempre na coluna 0.

Identificadores são muito importantes no código, dar visibilidade para eles é fundamental.

Answer (score 4):

A [FAQ tinha uma resposta referente a isso](https://web.archive.org/web/20160312185432/https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/faq.html#why-have-type-declarations-on-the-right), mas foi removida:

> **Why have type declarations on the right?**
>
> We believe it makes the code more readable. Besides, it enables some
>   nice syntactic features, for instance, it is easy to leave type
>   annotations out. Scala has also proven pretty well this is not a
>   problem.

Ou, em tradução livre:

> **Por que declarações de tipo na direita?**
>
> Acreditamos que torna o código mais legível. Além do mais, permite a adição de
>   algumas características interessantes de sintaxe. É fácil, por exemplo, deixar de lado anotações de tipo. 
>   Scala também provou que isso não é um problema.

Comment: "type declarations" --> "anotações de tipo"? Eu preferiria traduzir como "declarações de tipo". Além disso, a palavra "nice" se perdeu na tradução, sugiro colocá-la como "interessantes" ou "boas".

Comment: @VictorStafusa obrigado pelas sugestões!